# Imported ebookdroid android app failed generate R.java

Tags: java, android, ant

Hello i am trying to run EBookdroid reader on my eclipse. I have downloaded all source code. 
I copied all project to workspace and then imported to eclipse but when i import project into eclipse there is no R.java file generated. 
I tried to clean project but still with no luck. There are shown some warnings in build.xml, but i don't think that this is important generating R.java file.

Maybe someone had this problem i could help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Are there any errors in the 'problems' tab/thingy ?

Comment: yes there lots off warnings but no errors

Answer (score -1):

I tried to do the same thing few hours ago. Still cannot run ebookdroid properly but at least the R error portion has been cleared.

In short, check if you have android sdk correspond to target=android-xxxx

For me, after I install Android SDK 4.x and 3.0 and 3.1 via Android SDK Manager, that error dissapear